# Right Angle Triangle Sets

Tags: trigonometry

Hi I was wondering about this and don't know how to solve it so thought I could ask about it here.
If $A^2 + B^2 = X^2$ and $A^2 + C^2 = Y^2$ and $B^2 + C^2 = Z^2$ 
all are whole numbers and $A,B$ $A,C$ $B,C$ all form right angles in their respective triangles.
Is there any solution or sets of numbers that fit.
Regards Rob 
edit :- If there are many sets just the first few is fine.

Comment: Please [see this Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick) It gives a long list, and how to generate more.

Comment: Thanks I was just reading wiki before I saw your answer and this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I was just reading wiki before I saw your answer and this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple explains why my question can't be answered, one number needs to odd, and the other one even, so if both A,B and B,C are first part of a Pythagorean primitive triple, then B,C are either both even or both odd and can never make a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: You're correct that *primitive* Pythagorean triples consist of an odd and even "leg", but your question doesn't say that all three (or *any*) of the given relations have to be *primitive*. As André mentions, Wikipedia's ["Euler Brick" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick) explains that your question *can* be answered, and indeed that it has infinitely many solutions.